# How to execute join between three slow change dimensions sort by all start date columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join data between three slow change dimension type 2. When I query the result, the sort by date between the dimensions are not as expected.

I have the slow change dimensions below:

Table Subsidiaries

| id | name | subsidiary | department | start_date_dep | end_date_dep | last_record_flg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | AL | Engineering | 2005-10-01 | 2013-01-01 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | AL | Sales | 2013-01-01 | 2014-05-01 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | NY | Sales | 2014-05-01 |  | 1 |
| 38 | Ivy Johnson | NY | Sales | 2020-06-01 |  | 1 |

Table Functions

| id | function | start_date_fun | end_date_fun | last_record_flg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | operator | 2005-10-01 | 2009-08-01 | 0 |
| 1 | leader | 2009-08-01 | 2011-10-01 | 0 |
| 1 | manager | 2011-10-01 | 2017-07-01 | 0 |
| 1 | director | 2017-07-01 |  | 1 |
| 38 | operator | 2020-06-01 |  | 1 |

Table Graduations

| id | university_graduation | conclusion_date | last_record_flg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bachelor | 15/12/2005 | 0 |
| 1 | master | 15/12/2008 | 1 |
| 38 | bachelor | 15/12/2014 | 1 |

The desired result is:

| id | name | subsidiary | department | start_date_dep | end_date_dep | last_record_flg | function | start_date_fun | end_date_fun | last_record_flg | university_graduation | conclusion_date | last_record_flg | max_date | seq | start | end | last_record_flg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | AL | Engineering | 2005-10-01 | 2013-01-01 | 0 | operator | 2005-10-01 | 2009-08-01 | 0 | bachelor | 2005-12-15 | 0 | 2005-12-15 | 1 | 2005-10-01 | 2008-12-15 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | AL | Engineering | 2005-10-01 | 2013-01-01 | 0 | operator | 2005-10-01 | 2009-08-01 | 0 | master | 2008-12-15 | 1 | 2008-12-15 | 1 | 2008-12-15 | 2009-08-01 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | AL | Engineering | 2005-10-01 | 2013-01-01 | 0 | leader | 2009-08-01 | 2011-10-01 | 0 | master | 2008-12-15 | 1 | 2009-08-01 | 1 | 2009-08-01 | 2011-10-01 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | AL | Engineering | 2005-10-01 | 2013-01-01 | 0 | manager | 2011-10-01 | 2017-07-01 | 0 | master | 2008-12-15 | 1 | 2011-10-01 | 1 | 2011-10-01 | 2013-01-01 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | AL | Sales | 2013-01-01 | 2014-05-01 | 0 | manager | 2011-10-01 | 2017-07-01 | 0 | master | 2008-12-15 | 1 | 2013-01-01 | 1 | 2013-01-01 | 2014-05-01 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | NY | Sales | 2014-05-01 | NULL | 1 | manager | 2011-10-01 | 2017-07-01 | 0 | master | 2008-12-15 | 1 | 2014-05-01 | 1 | 2014-05-01 | 2017-07-01 | 0 |
| 1 | John Doe | NY | Sales | 2014-05-01 | NULL | 1 | director | 2017-07-01 | NULL | 1 | master | 2008-12-15 | 1 | 2017-07-01 | 1 | 2017-07-01 | NULL | 1 |
| 38 | Ivy Johnson | NY | Sales | 2020-06-01 | NULL | 1 | operator | 2020-06-01 | NULL | 1 | bachelor | 2014-12-15 | 1 | 2020-06-01 | 1 | 2020-06-01 | NULL | 1 |

I tried with CROSS APPLY, but is returning only one line for each id. I'm trying with CASE WHEN but the query output is not exactly equal the desired result. In my return the column '**FUNCTION**' and '**START_DATE_FUN**' not follow the sequence (sort) presented in the desired result, the same occur for columns '**UNIVERSITY_GRADUATION**' and '**CONCLUSION_DATE**'.

The query:

```
select 
    *
from(
    select 
        tb.*
        ,row_number() over(partition by tb.id,tb.max_date order by tb.max_date) as seq
        ,tb.max_date as [start]
        ,lead( tb.max_date ) over( partition by tb.id order by tb.max_date ) as [end] 
        ,case when lead( tb.max_date ) over( partition by tb.id order by tb.max_date ) is null then 1 else 0 end as last_record_flg
    from(
        select 
            sb.id
            ,sb.[name]
            ,sb.subsidiary
            ,sb.department
            ,sb.start_date_dep
            ,sb.end_date_dep
            ,sb.last_record_flg as lr_sb
            ,fc.[function]
            ,fc.start_date_fun
            ,fc.end_date_fun
            ,fc.last_record_flg as lr_fc
            ,gd.university_graduation
            ,gd.end_date_grad
            ,gd.last_record_flg as lr_gd
            ,case
                when sb.start_date_dep >= fc.start_date_fun and sb.start_date_dep >= gd.end_date_grad then sb.start_date_dep
                when fc.start_date_fun >= sb.start_date_dep and fc.start_date_fun >= gd.end_date_grad then fc.start_date_fun
                else gd.end_date_grad
            end as max_date
        from 
            #Subsidiaries as sb
            left outer join #Functions as fc
                on sb.id = fc.id
            left outer join #Graduations as gd
                on sb.id = gd.id
    ) as tb
) as tb2
where
    tb2.seq = 1
```

Below the DDL:

```
create table #Subsidiaries (
    id int
    ,[name] varchar(15)
    ,subsidiary varchar(2)
    ,department varchar(15)
    ,start_date_dep date
    ,end_date_dep date
    ,last_record_flg bit
)
go

insert into #Subsidiaries values
(1,'John Doe','AL','Engineering','2005-10-01','2013-01-01',0),
(1,'John Doe','AL','Sales','2013-01-01','2014-05-01',0),
(1,'John Doe','NY','Sales','2014-05-01',null,1),
(38,'Ivy Johnson','NY','Sales','2020-06-01',null,1)
go

create table #Functions (
    id int
    ,[function] varchar(15)
    ,start_date_fun date
    ,end_date_fun date
    ,last_record_flg bit
)
go

insert into #Functions values
(1,'operator','2005-10-01','2009-08-01',0),
(1,'leader','2009-08-01','2011-10-01',0),
(1,'manager','2011-10-01','2017-07-01',0),
(1,'director','2017-07-01',null,1),
(38,'operator','2020-06-01',null,1)
go

create table #Graduations (
    id int
    ,university_graduation varchar(15)
    ,end_date_grad date
    ,last_record_flg bit
)
go

insert into #Graduations values
(1,'bachelor','2005-12-15',0),
(1,'master','2008-12-15',1),
(38,'bachelor','2014-12-15',1)
go
```

Comment: I;m not following in which order you want your result to be. your expected output looks  the same as what your query currently returns.

Comment: Maybe show us what you want to get back. As its confusing what you have put down. E.g. you have your 3 tables what do you want  the result to look like

Comment: I've heard of other folks, specifically dealing with HR data where attributes for an employee and organizational relationships are spread across dozens of SCD tables, dealing with it by generating a record for each day for the validity period of the record and performing joins with that date as part of the key. That's very heavy handed, but it solves the big problem of date period intersection. It's unfortunate that so few RDBMSs support a "Period" data type where period intersection is a built in feature (like Postgres or Teradata).

Comment: I updated the question content to be more clear about the expected result and where my query is returning different of the expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case when someone find the same difficult to join two or more SCD type 2, I could find a reference in this link https://sqlsunday.com/2014/11/30/joining-two-scd2-tables/ (SQL Sunday) that help me to build the query and use the range intervals in the join condition to return result as desired.